# How to tell user if username is already taken in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a very simple login GUI and it's almost finished. However when a user tries to register an account which has the same username as a previously registered account, it overrides the registered account with the new one's password and level details. Is there a way to prevent a new user from using the same username as another account?

```
def register_user():
 
                username_info = username.get()
                passcode_info = passcode.get()
                level_info = level.get()
 
                file = open(username_info,"w")
                file.write(username_info+"\n")
                file.write(passcode_info+"\n")
                file.write(level_info)
                file.close()

                if level.get() != "":
                    Label(top, text="Registration Successful", fg="gray", bg="white", font=("times new roman", 12)).pack()
                else:
                    Label(top, text="Registration Unsuccessful: Please Select Level*", fg="gray", bg="white", font=("times new roman", 12)).pack()
                    os.remove(username_info)
```

Comment: 1. Append to a file or read it whole and write it whole. That's why you're always overwriting it  `w` mode cleans the file and allows writing to it. 2. Read the file before trying to write it, check is username is unique then.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm kind of new to Python. Could you please go into more detail as to how I would fix it? Particularly 1.

Comment: @cpanj3 either use `open('file.extension', 'a')` and then use `.write` or `open('file.extension')` read the contents to a variable then add to that variable, then `open('file.extension', 'w')` and `.write()` that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the user file already exists.  If yes, show "user already exists" error.

Also better to create the label for the result once outside the function and update it inside the function.

```py
def register_user():
 
    username_info = username.get()
    passcode_info = passcode.get()
    level_info = level.get()

    if level_info and username_info and passcode_info:
        # all information exists
        if os.path.exists(username_info):
            result.config(text="Registration Unsuccessful: User already exists!", fg="red")
        else:
            with open(username_info, "w") as f:
                f.write("\n".join([username_info, passcode_info, level_info]))
            result.config(text="Registration Successful", fg="green")
    else:
        result.config(text="Registration Unsuccessful: Please input all information", fg="red")

...
result = Label(top, bg="white", font=("times new roman", 12))
result.pack()
...
```